# Output of ls command confusing for KVM raw image on XFS

Tags: kvm, xfs, sparse-files

After creating a new VM on a raw image using `virt-install`, I tried to verify that the image was a sparse file, but was unable to determine using the `ls` command.

```
ls -ls myvm.img
1048576000 -rw------- 1 root root 1073741824000 Nov 4 15:49 myvm.img
```

From this, it appears to be a 1 TB image with only about 1 GB of allocated space. However, if I use the -h flag, I get this:

```
ls -lsh myvm.img
1001G -rw------- 1 root root 1000G Nov 4 15:49 myvm.img
```

Likewise the `du` command shows:

```
du -h myvm.img
1001G myvm.img
```

And this:

```
qemu-img info myvm.img
file format: raw
virtual size: 1.0T
disk size: 1.0T
```

If I atttempt to backup the image, it tries to copy the whole 1 TB:

```
tar -Scf myvm.tar myvm.img
```

So what's going on here? There seems to be some indication, based on the first command, that it is a sparse file, but it doesn't appear to be. Is this an oddity of XFS?

Comment: What does `filefrag`  say?

Comment: @frostschutz `filefrag` says "15 extents found." `xfs_bmap` doesn't list any holes.

Comment: `filefrag` would also list the type of extents, whether fully allocated, reserved, or what. Then you'd know whether your file is sparse at all.

Comment: @frostschutz Which flags would you use for that. I tried everything listed in the manpage, and nothing produced the info you described. I'm on CentOS 7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ls` and `du` do not contradict each other.  (They use the same system calls).

`ls -s` lists size in blocks (of 1 kilobyte[*] by default).

1048576000 * 1024 = 1073741824000

[*] cough, kibibyte.

Comment: That does answer my original question. I"m still wondering, though, why virt-install didn't create a sparse file, when that's supposed to be the default for raw images.

Comment: odd, yes.  note that virt-install isn't particularly magic.  you can test immediately aborting (quitting) the installer & the image will still be created.  One possibility I can imagine is that if you request encryption in the installer, it might write random data to the entire virtual disk.

Comment: It seems that Redhat has altered the default behavior of the libvirt commands. The same goes for `virsh vol-create-as`. Apparently, they don't like people using sparse files. Either that, or the documentation is out of date. I haven't tested this on another Linux distro.